# Subclass SKScene to load my sprite kit file

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, subclass

I'm try to subclass an SKscene and assign to it my editor scene

but I'm getting the error says "Cannot assign to property: 'scene' is a get-only property"

How I do correctly subclass the SKscene

here my attempt:

```
class DoorScene: SKScene {
    
    override init(size: CGSize) {

        super.init(size: size)

        self.backgroundColor = .black

    }
    
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    
    
    func loadSKscene()->SKScene{ // load screenPFD
        guard let scene = SKScene(fileNamed: "/Asset.scnassets/ECAM SYSTEM/lower_ECAM.sks") else {return SKScene()}
        scene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
        
        return scene
    }
    
    
    
    
    override func sceneDidLoad() {
        loadimmage()
    }
    
    
    func loadimmage() {
        
        let background = loadSKscene()
        self.scene = background

        
    }
    
    
    
    
}
```

Comment: What does '->SKScene' mean?

Comment: load my sks file and return a SKScene which the I try to load into my custom DoorScene with DoorScene.scene = loadSKscene but getting error says scene is only a get property

Comment: Return the class itself?  It doesn't make sense, does it?